# Is there a way to use the MongoDB C# driver synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, async-await, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a 2 layered C# project. The 1st one is a data layer which connects to mongodb and sends collections to the web service layer. The problem is that I couldn't find in the new driver non-`async` methods (i.e. synchronous).

Is there a way to use synchronous methods with the C# driver for mongodb version 2.0?

Hint: Is it possible to run mongodb shell functions with c#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: In v2.2 of the driver they are adding synchronous versions for all the async operations that are synchronous *almost* all the way down. If you can't use async-await for some reason this is the next best option.

---

You **should** be using the `async` operations as the driver is `async` and the operations are inherently asynchronous (being mainly I/O, usually to a remote server).

But, if you must keep things synchronous you have 3 options, ordered from the most recommended to the least:

1. Keep using the old (v1.x) version of the driver with the synchronous API.
2. Use the new driver, but with the legacy API (`client.GetServer`). It requires a different nuget package (named Legacy) and has both types of API.
3. Use the `async` operations and block on them with `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait`.

The old version is preferred because it uses synchronous I/O operations which is usually better than using `async` ones and blocking on them.

The other options both block on `async` operations but the legacy driver is thoughtfully implemented, tested and maintained so the blocking is done in a good way (i.e. using `ConfigureAwait(false)` and `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` everywhere)

Answer (score 4):

> You should be using the async operations as the driver is async and the operations are inherently asynchronous (being mainly I/O, usually to a remote server).

NO! Occam's razor! The simplest answer is typically the correct one. async programming is inheritantly more difficult to program and debug. Why be forced to use it for simple tasks.

Here is what I do to force sync at least within my own thread.

```
var c1 = collection.Find(filter);
var y = c1.ToListAsync();
y.Wait();
var w = y.Result.FirstOrDefault();
```

Perfect case in point. Why have 4 lines of code when only one is necessary.

Comment: You don't need that much code, why not just do `collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result.FirstOrDefault()`? And comparing this the sync one liner `collection.Find(filter).ToList().FirstOrDefault()` it isn't so much of a difference, but you are right about the internal implementation and your point about Occam's Razor so +1, either way what the Mongo C# team did is ridiculous.

Comment: not sure what Occam has to do with wasting threads on potentially lengthy operations. Ugly code? take F#'s Async computational expressions and be golden